# What's the most efficient way to copy elements of a C# multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, optimization, multidimensional-array, copy

What's the most efficient way to nest my loops when copying from one multidimensional array to another in C#? The upper and lower bounds of each array are different, so I don't *think* `Array.Copy()` will do the job for me. I currently have the following:

```
for (int x = lower.X; x <= upper.X; x++)
{
    for (int y = lower.Y; y <= upper.Y; y++)
    {
        for (int z = lower.Z; z <= upper.Z; z++)
        {
            copy[x, y, z] = Elements[x, y, z];
        }
    }
}
```

This is a relatively low-level optimization, so will the compiler take care of this for me? Is there a better way to copy elements of a multidimensional array when the destination has different upper and lower bounds?

Comment: Are the overall sizes of the arrays the same - i.e. do they contain the same number of elements overall?  Array.Copy is definitely worth a try if this is the case.

Comment: No. `copy` is always larger than `Elements`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array.Copy will work for you, but only to replace the innermost loop. You will have to calculate the source and destination indicies yourself, but that is certainly doable. The [documentation for `Array.Copy(Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) explains how to do the math on indices so you can specify the source and target locations.

I highly recommend using Array.Copy everywhere it makes sense to use it, because it is crazy-fast. They do some serious assembler-foo to make it work well.

**UPDATE**

I am not sure how close this is to correct, because I haven't tried it, but this is something like how I think it might go:

```
int xLength = upper.X - lower.X + 1;
int yLength = upper.Y - lower.Y + 1;
int zLength = upper.Z - lower.Z + 1;

Array copy = Array.CreateInstance(Elements.GetType(), new { xLength, yLength, zLength }, new {lower.X, lower.Y, lower.Z});

int skippedX = lower.X - Elements.GetLowerBound(0);
int skippedY = lower.Y - Elements.GetLowerBound(1);
int skippedZ = lower.Z - Elements.GetLowerBound(2);

int sourceDim0Size = Elements.GetLength(1) * Elements.GetLength(2);
int sourceDim1Size = Elements.GetLength(2);

for (int x = 0; x < xLength; x++)
{
     for (int y = 0; y < yLength; y++)
     {
         int destinationIndex = x * yLength * zLength + y * zLength;
         int sourceIndex = (x + skippedX) * sourceDim0Size 
                           + (y + skippedY) * sourceDim1Size
                           + skippedZ;
         Array.Copy(Elements, sourceIndex, copy, 0, zLength);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Buffer.BlockCopy()`. If it won't work in one step, copy first multidimensional array into single dimension array and then copy this single dimensional array to second multidimensional array.

References:

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/buffer-blockcopy
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx

Comment: This code is in a generic class, so the array might contain object references or other non-primitives. Will `Buffer.BlockCopy()` still work properly?

Comment: No. It does not work for non-primitives. Array.Copy() seems the best bet then.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this can't get any simpler.  It seems like you are doing a 3 dimensional pixel copy from one surface to another - short of hardware acceleration, I think it has to go one by one.

Well, if you have multiple cores, it might be faster to go a thread per core.

Maybe someone who know more for certin will chime in...

As a footnote, I'm curious if your example is a case where non-managed code would significantly outperform...